# Сформировать SQL запрос

Tags: sql

Друзья, подскажите как реализовать вот такой SQL запрос:
Выбрать всё из таблицы profiles где lastact (datetime) меньше now() на 3 минуты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вычесть из now() lastfact, может?

Comment: Пробивал вот так вот: 
`SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE (NOW() - lastactivity) > 5`
- Получаю ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Всё решилось вот таким вот путём:

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP( dt2 ) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP( dt1 )
```

Подробнее, кому ещё нужно: [ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=28&id=979](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=28&id=979)